# adherence values ​of a recurring sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm wondering if an adherence values ​​of a recurring sequence:
            $u_{n+1}=f\left(u_{n}\right)$
is a fixed point of one of the compsite $f^{\circ k}$ .  Thank you

Comment: bonjour et bienvenu sur ce site. Ici on parle anglais, donc il faut que tu réécrives ta question en anglais sinon elle sera supprimée. (Hello and welcome to this website. This is an english speaking site, so you should translate your question in english, otherwise it will be deleted)

Comment: Hello, I'm wondering if an adhesion values ​​of a recurring sequence:
$ u_ {n + 1} = f \ left (u_ {n} \ right) $ is a fixed point of one of the comps $ f ^ {\ mathrm {ok}} $. Thank you

Comment: There is something which is fantastic in my humble opinion (I must precise that I am French) : we have two languages for communicating : Mathematics and English. Even if the second is not good, the first one allows to understand eachother. So, please, edit your post. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not, not necessarily.

As an example, if you take $f(x)=x^2-2$, then one can prove that there are some $u_0 \in [-2,2]$ for which the set of adherence values of the sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is all of $[-2,2]$. In particular, $u_0$ itself is an adherence value, and it is not periodic under $f$.

Another example is when you take $f$ to be a rotation of angle $\theta$, where $\frac{\theta}{\pi}$ is irrational. Then one can prove that for any starting point $u_0$ on the unit circle, the set of adherence values of $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is all of the circle. And such a rotation has no periodic points.